# replacing a string deletes everything in text

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program for this question: *"Write a program that will ask a string and a file name from the user and then removes all the occurrences of that string from that text file."*

This is what I have so far:

```
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.*;

    public class RemoveText {
        public static void main(String[] args){

    //creates a scanner to read the user's file name
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
    String fileName = input.nextLine();

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(fileName);
    java.io.File newFile = new java.io.File(fileName);
    Scanner stringToRemove = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string you wish to remove: ");
    String s1 = stringToRemove.nextLine();

    //creating input and output files
    try {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        //reads data from a file
        while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
            s1 += inputFile.nextLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //supposed to replace each instance of the user input string 
    //but instead deletes everything on the file and i don't know why
    String s2 = s1.replaceAll(s1, "");

    try {
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(newFile);
        output.write(s2);
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //closing various scanners
    input.close();
    stringToRemove.close();
  }
}
```

But for some reason, instead of replacing the string with whitespace, the entire text file becomes empty. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Okay, so I took everyone's advice and managed to fix the variable problem by introducing a third String variable and using more descriptive variable names.

```
   Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   String stringToRemove = s1.nextLine();
   String fileContents = null;

   try {
    //stuff here
      while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
      fileContents += inputFile.nextLine();
    } catch { //more stuff }

   String outputContent = fileContents.replaceAll(stringToRemove, "");
```

My issue now is that the beginning of the new file starts with "null" before relaying the new content.

Comment: Cause you're saving both the text and the string-to-remove in the same variable ? (and then doing: `s1.replaceAll(s1, "")`)

Comment: choose good names for your variables. Using `stringToRemove` for the first `s1` (and renaming your current `stringToRemove` to `input` or similar), and using `fileContents` instead of the second use of `s1`, would have done wonders to explain why `fileContents.replaceAll(stringToRemove, "")` is correct and `stringToRemove.replaceAll(stringToRemove, "")` returns an empty string

Answer (score 3):

```
String s2 = s1.replaceAll(s1, "");
```

the first parameter of replaceAll method is what you are looking for to replace, and you are looking for s1, you are saying with this code clean all s1 content...

Answer (score 1):

Where you went wrong is that you appended the file content to s1 which is the string you want to remove.
Try introduce s3 and then do

s2 = s3.replaceAll(s1, "");

Comment: Btw, it's inefficient to read the entire content into memory. If the file content is long, your program will run out of memory.